Custom Input field not displayed in Woocommerce Product Page
I am trying to add a Custom Input field in The Woocommerce Product page. The Input field will take a pincode.
// Add custom input field to WooCommerce product page
add_action('woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'add_custom_input_field');

function add_custom_input_field() {
    echo '<div class="custom-input-field">
            <label for="custom_pincode_field">Enter Pincode:</label>
            <input type="text" id="custom_pincode_field" name="custom_pincode_field" placeholder="Enter your pincode" required>
          </div>';
}

// Validate the custom pincode input field
add_filter('woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'validate_custom_pincode_field', 10, 3);

function validate_custom_pincode_field($passed, $product_id, $quantity) {
    if (empty($_POST['custom_pincode_field'])) {
        wc_add_notice(__('Please enter your pincode.'), 'error');
        return false;
    }
    return $passed;
}

I was expecting to see this input field on the product page but it doesn't appear there. I have tried to add this code to function.php file but it's not working.

I have tested and it shows up. Maybe your theme is overwriting it? If you don't have child theme add one and try again. Another option is if your theme removes this filter and uses its own one.

This is certainly because of your theme own customizations… To see if it's related to your theme, first make a database backup, then install Storefront theme and activate it… Then add your code to Storefront theme functions.php file. The custom field should appear on product pages and in this case, you should contact your theme authors via their support pages.

Have you checked this?

@DhruvPandya  Note that this question is not about custom fields on admin side, it's about displaying an input field in frontend single product pages, so your link is useless.

Check the version of Elementor (if you are using it). I had a template to display products, where it had the price and inside that price it had the input with the PHP filter. That input disappeared.
I downgraded the Elementor plugin version to 3.24.0 and Hello Elementor and it started working again.
